# Preserve Spark partition order with text file serialization

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, persistence

Spark can serialize a dataset of strings to a set of text files, one for each partition. However it does not seem to respect the order of partitions when reading back these text files.

Say I have a RDD `myDataset` of 8 elements, partitioned into 4 partitions. I can serialize it:

```
scala> val myDataset = sc.parallelize(Array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), 4)
scala> myDataset.saveAsTextFile("/tmp/myDataset")
```

It is serialized as follows:

- file `/tmp/myDataset/part-00000` contains two lines: `0` and `1`
- file `/tmp/myDataset/part-00001` contains two lines: `2` and `3`
- file `/tmp/myDataset/part-00002` contains two lines: `4` and `5`
- file `/tmp/myDataset/part-00003` contains two lines: `6` and `7`

Now if I read my dataset again:

```
scala> spark.read.textFile("/tmp/myDataset").take(8)
res43: Array[String] = Array(6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 1)
```

I would expect Spark to read the partitions in the order it wrote them, which would preserve the ordering of the elements in the dataset.

Is there a way to preserve this order?

Comment: Could downvoters explain why they do not like this question?

Comment: Hi @pintoch, have you been able to solve the preservation issue? I'm experiencing the same.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the answer. Yes, it does work now, but there is no partitioner for the loaded data. I think I'm going to be looking for a way to attach a partitioner now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be [a known bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5300) due to the fact that the underlying function used to list files on a local file system, `File.listFiles()`, does not sort its return value.

One workaround is to implement a dedicated `FileInputFormat` which sorts the file names:

```java
public class OrderedTextInputFormat extends TextInputFormat {

    @Override
    protected List<FileStatus> listStatus(JobContext job) throws IOException  {
        List<FileStatus> files = super.listStatus(job);
        files.sort(new Comparator<FileStatus>() {

            @Override
            public int compare(FileStatus lhs, FileStatus rhs) {
                return lhs.getPath().compareTo(rhs.getPath());
            }

        });
        return files;
    }
}
```